# Can I change laptop 's quad core processor with dual core processor?

Tags: processor

I have Asus x553MA laptop with quad core processor

Intel® Bay Trail-M Quad Core Pentium N3540 Processor,

Specs here 
https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X553MA/specifications/

can I replace it with with my old laptop Lenovo B450 dual core processor?

old laptop specs here 
http://mobilespecs.net/laptop/Lenovo/Lenovo_B450.html

Pentium 2100 MHz

Processor Model:T4300

Number of Cores:2

L2 cache:1 MB

The system bus:800 MHz

Comment: AKAIK, laptop CPUs cannot be replaced with newer CPUs as they are generally soldered onto the motherboard, same goes the GPU, if it has one. Your best bet right now is to either replace the whole motherboard in the laptop, or buy a new laptop with a dual core inside( although IDK why you would do that as more cores outrank more threada anyday)

Comment: Technical support request.

Comment: I don't think you can swap the processors between the laptops, as on laptops, manufacturers usually weld the processors right on the mainboard.

Comment: @E.Nunn a big NO! it's not a technical support request, it's about enthusiasm of how I can upgrade /play with my machine. Which is the main tool of as software engineer.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong there, this is a site to recommend hardware to people. Where in the question are we recommending hardware please? Please read this SE's help section.

Comment: It says and I quote, 
"Hardware Recommendations is a community-run website to help you find a specific product for your needs. That means you can ask for a recommendation for hardware to perform a specific task. However, you should be aware that "hardware" is not an all-encompassing term. In essence, we can help you if you're looking for a recommendation for hardware that is "an electronic item that is, interfaces with, or connects to a computer to operate".

Comment: And the answer to your question by the way, is no, as laptop cpu's are welded. Socketed Laptop CPUs have hardly hit the market yet, and are very expensive.

Answer (score 2):

If the socket is the same, yes. But personally I wouldn't, multithreading really speeds things up.